# What to Bundle in VS15 MVC Project Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm experimenting with using angularjs in a .NET MVC environment. I have placed the usual Razor statement @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular") in the head of my  _layout.cshtml, and yes it does produce the desired  element, as I see when I do a 'View Page Source' on the resultant page. The tag I'm trying to use angularjs on is simply a  run-of-the-mill   tag.  I don't see any errors, and everything else is working fine, but it doesn't appear that the browser is calling the controller before it renders my  element.

When does the browser execute the controller code associated with the ng-controller attribute? Does it matter where I place the definition of the controller? I'm simply using the usual angular.module method inside a  element to define it, like so:

```
    angular.module('app',[]).controller("FredCtrl",
                   function($scope){ $scope.message = "- - -"; })
```

Yet $scope.message seems to be empty. Any suggestions?

Do I need to bundle something else other than just ~/Scripts/angular.js for something so simple?
Thanks for any assistance.

---

No, the console tab in the Firefox F12 tools doesn't show any errors. Here is the simple h2 element I'm trying to apply angularjs to

```
    <h2 ng-constroller="FredCtrl">Getting started {{message}}</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app',[]).controller("FredCtrl",
                   function($scope){ $scope.message = "- - - -"; })
    </script>
```

and yes I do have the ng-app attribute set in my body tag, like so:

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

---

Oh, and I tried it in Chrome as well, with the same result. Everything seems to be working just fine. No errors show up in the Console tab for Chrome as well. I just don't see my $scope.message show up in the display.

Comment: Please add your html as well. Are you using your browser's developer tools (F12)? Have you looked in the console of developer tools for errors?

Comment: I am obviously completely blind!! Now I see what any of you reading my code probably saw immediately. I spelled 'controller' as 'constroller'. How I happened to overlook that, I can't imagine, but, of course, I did. As you might expect, after having finished my 'stroll', I simply removed the offending letter 's' and naturally it now works beautifully. I suppose there is some poetic justice in the fact that the letters preceding the 's' spell 'con' and the letters following the 's' spell 'troll'. My apologies. A useful reminder, I suppose, that the prospect of syntactical errors always looms.

Comment: @Tallisfan I could not find a solution to my problem, your post helped me a lot in my work. Thanks Tallisfan!